# How to set location for desktop in Windows 8?

Tags: geolocation, windows-8

Working on a prototype Windows 8 Metro App and wanted to use the `Geolocator`. I know how to simulate the location using the simulator. But I was just curious if there was a way to set the location information for my actual desktop (not lucky enough to have been to BUILD last year and get a tablet...)

Comment: Are you not getting a location when you run the app? I thought that if you set the DesiredAccuracy not to High, it will determine your location based on something else (WAN etc,) than a GPS sensor. Have you enable locations in the Windows 8 settings?

Comment: @ChristiaanV, nope, I am not getting a location. As for settings, if you are refering to the charms -> settings, yes, I have enabled it. I'll check further if for some odd reason it's disabled at the higher level... Regardless, I would like to find a way to override this at some level. If it uses the ISP, in my case, it's like 100 miles off. And I'd like not to have to purchase a GPS device just for that. Or do routers/modems provide the ability to set this up?